# Modifying and running VB.net project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to modify and run existing VB Visual Studio 2010 projects in Visual Studio Code? I have some VB.NET projects that I would like to open in visual studio code and I haven't found anything online that says whether or not this is possible. Drag and drop functionality isn't necessary for me, I only care about being able to run the source code.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: VS Code is only an editor with code highlighting, Intellisense and so on. There are no compilers integrated. You can use the free Visual Studio 2015 Community, but it's not a native Linux program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Code to edit any text file you want.

Comment: So it doesn't allow for running a program? That's a shame. The webpage for it made it seem (to me anyways) like you can compile and run Visual Studio projects with it.

Comment: @AlexMcVittie: It can run new DNX projects; I don't think it can currently run older MSBuild projects.